# Date mismatch of question and edit-of-question

Tags: bug, timestamps

Just came across an older answer of mine and was surprised, that the "asked" date of the question was something in 2013, while my "edited" was of 2011. Strange reversion of causality ...

Here is the question: [MSE formula-for-sum-of-logarithms-lnnm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394520/formula-for-sum-of-logarithms-lnnm)

[image]

Comment: Jul 11 means Jul 11 of 2014. Not July of 2011.

Comment: In fact, if you hover your mouse over the edit time stamp, the toolhint should show you the full date-string for the edit, which seems to be almost noon on Jul 11, 2014, measured relative to UTC.

Comment: ohh my god... @willie

Comment: ... time to retract the silly question...

Comment: Don't worry, any of us can make that mistake.

Comment: @Willie: Chuck Norris can't make mistakes. Reality aligns to what he claims whenever there is an inconsistency.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That *probably* isn't true.

Comment: @Asaf, has Chuck Norris ever gone on record with regard to The Continuum Hypothesis?

Comment: @DisplayName: Chuck Norris would disagree, and in event of a dispute Chuck Norris is right.

Comment: @Gerry: Yes, but he then killed all those who heard him, since he likes to see us struggle..

Comment: I have added a screenshot. As it was established that this is not a bug, maybe the question could be retagged as ([meta-tag:support]). @WillieWong I guess your comment could be posted as answer. (Maybe even an images illustrating it can be [found somewhere](http://images.google.com/images?q=hover+timestamp+site:meta.stackexchange.com). However, I do not know how to capture the tooltip on a screenshot - it disappears when I press a key, in this case Ctrl+PrintScreen.)

Comment: As I found out now, it was sufficient to use PrintScreen and not Ctrl+PrintScreen. http://i.stack.imgur.com/JxTcI.png

Comment: @Martin : why not retag it as "Chuckle"? <chuckle> (just kidding)

Comment: I thought that [Gauss is our Chuck Norris](http://www.gaussfacts.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's answer this question, so as to move it off of the "unanswered" list.

July $11$ here means July $11$, $2014$ (or whatever year this screenshot was taken in). The year is hidden, if you're reading it in the same year when the question/answer was edited, answered, and/or asked, since if not, i) it would be redundant, and ii) it would take up too much space (thus again returning to i)). As Willie Wong says in [his second comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16646/date-mismatch-of-question-and-edit-of-question#comment61339_16646):

> In fact, if you hover your mouse over the edit time stamp, the toolhint should show you the full date-string for the edit, which seems to be almost noon on Jul 11, 2014, measured relative to UTC. –  [Willie Wong♦](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/1543/willie-wong). $25$th August $2014$, $15:00:36$Z <sup>1 2</sup>

As Martin suggests in the comments, see [these pictures](https://www.google.com/search?q=hover+timestamp+site:meta.stackexchange.com&gws_rd=ssl&tbm=isch) for what I'm talking about.

---

<sup>1</sup> I really don't know what the Z stands for. (To see the Z, hover you mouse above "$n$ days ago".)

<sup>2</sup> It turns out that the Z means Zulu time. See Asaf's comment below.

Comment: Z indicates this is Zulu time. Also known as UTC (or GMT, if you prefer Britcentric culture). [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks! I was confused as I'm used to seeing GMT, and not Z (I've seen UTC a few times as well).